# how to grab the hour from a timefield - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model and form with a TimeField and I want to make a change for the hour once the timefield is extracted from the form that was submitted and stored. I want to update the hour in the time. can anyone help me with this...

here is the view

```
start_time = cd['start_time']

hour = start_time.hour
new_hour = hour - int(alert)

update_time = start_time
update_time.hour = new_hour
update_time.save()
```

So the start_time is a timefield that submitted. 
I want to grab the hour from that start time to change it. how can i do that...

this is the error essage I am getting:

```
attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.time' objects is not writable
```

I want to grab the hour from the original time and updated/change it

Comment: If you want to set that attr, you can init new one time object to set it.

Answer (score 0):

datetime instances are immutable, but there is a method to get a new instance with one (or serveral) of the fields replaced with a different value. It's documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

So your example would become something like this:

```
start_time = cd['start_time']
update_time = start_time.replace(hour=start_time.hour - int(alert))
```

I'm not sure why you are calling `save` on update time. I'm assuming that's a mistake in your example.